# Sharepoint client object model. How to get current list view?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, client, sharepoint-api, sharepoint-clientobject

Sharepoint list contains 6 views.

I am staing on sharepoint page where items filtered by list view query.

how can i get current view or view title with **client object model**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Dim objmyList As SP.List = g_objCore.Security.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(“**Your List Name*”)
Dim objmyView As SP.View = objmyList.Views.GetByTitle(“*Your View Name*”)
```

as described in this example: http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/09/05/get-list-views-in-sharepoint-2010-client-object-model-programmatically/